# Energy lost in a resistor and its temperature

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

The power lost across a resistor is proportional to the square of the voltage drop across it. This means by increasing the voltage across the resistor, the energy lost in it in a given time grows non-linearly. Why is the energy loss not linear with voltage ?
I think the resistor temperature must grow linearly with voltage  - is that correct ?

Comment: The energy used over a fixed resistance per unit time is experimentally agreeing with the square of the voltage.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent you mean it's temprature will not rise linearly with voltage increasing?

Comment: *I think it must grow linearly.* Why?

Comment: *Maybe the physicist defined badly?* No.

Comment: @ghoster Why not?

Comment: @Ghoster Then I have to search about it's temprature rising soon. I will see you soon. thx.

Comment: “Why not” is not a physics argument. The moon is made of green cheese. Why not? Be serious.

Comment: @Ghoster Because someone has gone there and saw that, and that was not a chees.

Comment: And people have measured the energy dissipated in resistors as they varied the voltage and the current. And it wasn’t linear.

Comment: @Ghoster So I think i need first to know if temp is growing linearly or not, thx.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question was not posed well so although I understood it an was in the middle of writing a good answer, someone closed the question and I can't submit my answer :-(

Comment: All I cant fit here is a link, so check out https://brilliant.org/wiki/heat-dissipated-by-resistors/

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer and voted to reopen it.

Comment: I would also like to vote to reopen this issue, but don't know how (maybe I don't have enough points to do this?). I have my answer saved in another screen, waiting until the question is reopened and I can submit an answer.

Comment: Energy loss is linear with voltage if you keep the current constant by increasing the resistance proportionally to the voltage.

Comment: @seyyedmohammadsaadatmand "Ghoster So I think i need first to know if temp is growing linearly or not, thx." There is. no simple answer as to how temperature changes. it depends on the resistors environment and the heat transfer mechanisms involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is receiving some negative comments because of how it was worded (and its title), but it's actually an interesting question: Is there an **intuitive** explanation why is energy dissipation across a resistor $V^2/R$ and not something else, perhaps depending linearly on $V$?

Let me try to give you an intuitive explanation.

Let's look at an analogy: Imagine a waterfall. How much energy does the waterfall dissipate when the water hits the bottom (let's assume all the energy of the waterfall is indeed used - perhaps there is a power plant down there)?

In the waterfall, each drop of water falling has an energy depending on the *height* it started, its potential - let's call it $V$. The number of these drops per second is the *current* of water, let's call it $I$. The total energy per second (called **power**) of the waterfall is therefore the multiplication of these numbers: $P = VI$.

Exactly the same is true with electronics: The power dissipation (energy lost per time) of a resistor is $VI$. But what is the current $I$? According to Ohm's law, $I$ is itself proportional to $V$: $I = V/R$. Why? I think it makes intuitive sense - the bigger the voltage, the more likely it is to push electrons despite the resistance and the bigger the current gets.

So if we combine the intuitive (waterfall-like) formula $P=VI$ with Ohm's law $I=V/R$ we get $P=V^2/R$, exactly the formula we set out to explain.

According to the above derivation, the only way you could get $P$ proportional to $V$ (instead of $V^2$) would have been if Ohm's law was replaced by a statement that $I$ is *constant* in $V$: Increasing a battery's voltage would not increase the current, and decreasing the battery's volate would not decrease the current. I think intuitively, we know this is not the case (and of course, Ohm's law is well verified experimentally, and understood from first principles of quantum mechanics and statistics).

See also https://brilliant.org/wiki/heat-dissipated-by-resistors/.

Comment: The waterfall analogy is somewhat unlucky since a waterfall does not have resistance. The water is linearly accelerated. Better is perhaps a river where the current is saturated by resistance.

Comment: Right. The waterfall just explains the $P=VI$ part, not the whole story. Then as soon as you realize that $I$ itself also depends on $V$ and is not constant, you realize that $P$ isn't linear in $V$. I guess a sloped river which has both a potential and resistance can make a complete analogy, but I'm not sure how much intuition readers will have on such an example.

Comment: In your interresting waterfall analogy: think of water drops. how energy produced by power plant will grow by increasing the droplets velocity. I think this will be the correct answer and involving ohm's law here is not really intuitive here.

Comment: But, in such an example, would the droplets' initial velocity depend on the height of the waterfal (V)l? They wouldn't. So this waterfall analogy can't explain Ohm's law.

Comment: But I didn't mean initial velocity, I mean velocity in the moment of impinging the turbines blade. (thinking emoji) I mean neglect the water fall and consider just the drplets when hitting the turbine. maybe this is because number of droplets are not bound to their speed, these are independent, and this is why this example can't match to p=v^2. But your example lightened me why ... still thinking ...